# Update a property value without adding an additional value, in gremlin_node

Tags: node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have written this gremlin query to update a property:

```
g.V("7cb57dad-d261-29cb-b886-affcd7442b73").property('tname', "updated tribename")
```

Is this the correct way to update a property in gremlin-node? Or do I have to pass in single property to update a property without adding additional value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the prior value then you need the `single` keyword to be explicitly specified as in:

```
g.V("7cb57dad-d261-29cb-b886-affcd7442b73").
  property(single, 'tname', "updated tribename")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kelvin said you should use the single cardinality.

in gremlin-node you can import it like this:

```
const V_CARDINALITY = gremlin.process.cardinality;

g.V("7cb57dad-d261-29cb-b886-affcd7442b73").
  property(V_CARDINALITY.single, 'tname', "updated tribename")
```